# "Illegal start of expression" error with else if

Tags: java, if-statement, expression

I'm trying to do an else if statement within a switch, but I keep getting "illegal start of expression error." The error usually pops up at the <= within case 1. I tried adding parentheses and brackets to see if that was the issue, but it wasn't.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class InvoiceApp
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //Declare variables and Scanner object
            float subtotal;
            int customerType;
            double discountAmount;
            double discountPercent;
            double total;

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Prompt user for subtotal   
            System.out.println("Please enter the subtotal: ");

            //Read subtotal
            subtotal = keyboard.nextFloat();

            //Calculate Discount Rate
            switch(customerType) {
                case 1: if  (subtotal >= 500) discountPercent = 20;

                        else if (subtotal < 500 && <= 250) 
                            discountPercent = 15; 

                        else if (subtotal < 250 && <= 100) 
                            discountPercent = 10; 

                        else if (subtotal < 100) 
                            discountPercent = 0; 



            }
```

Comment: `subtotal < 500 && <= 250` is a syntax error: it's not clear what it's meant to mean: what is meant to be less than or equal to 250?

Answer (score 1):

```
if  (subtotal < 100) 
  discountPercent = 0;
else if (subtotal < 250) 
  discountPercent = 10;
else if (subtotal < 500) 
  discountPercent = 15;
else
  discountPercent = 20;
```

Comment: @RolandIllig what do you mean?

Comment: Each of the `else` should have the same distance from the left margin, and the assignments should be further to the right.

Answer (score -1):

```
subtotal < 500 && subtotal<= 250
```

Comment: Your answer is not actually a correct claim about the value of subtotal, but if I assume that you meant to write something like "Change `subtotal < 500 && <= 250` to `subtotal < 500 && subtotal<= 250`", then: that would address the syntax error, but would be a clear logic error.

Comment: @ruakh Maybe he meant (subtotal < 500 && subtotal >= 250).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14096286)

Comment: @DimaSan *"This does not provide an answer"* This is incorrect. The rules for "not an answer" are very strict and they generally say, that everything that tries to answer a question (any question, not necessarily this one) is an answer. Can be bad and may deserves a downvote, but it's still an answer. This post here is an unformatted fix of OPs first `else if`. Therefore it tries to answer, but in a rather DV worthy way.